# Spring Mongodb - Cannot write custom Converter for java.time.Period

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I'm using Spring `Cloud Brixton.SR4` with Spring Data MongoDB.

I have a very simple entity:

```
@Document
public class Foo{
    private Period period;

    //getter & setter
}
```

Because `java.time.Period` is not supported by `jsr310` I'm creating custom converters:

```
class Converters {
    @Component
    @WritingConverter
    static class PeriodToStringConverter implements Converter<Period, String> {
        @Override
        public String convert(Period period) {
            return period.toString();
        }
    }

    @ReadingConverter
    @Component
    static class StringToPeriodConverter implements Converter<String, Period> {

        @Override
        public Period convert(String s) {
            return Period.parse(s);
        }
    }
```

Now I register them in my configuration class extending `AbstractMongoConfiguration`:

```
    @Bean
    @Override
    public MappingMongoConverter mappingMongoConverter() throws Exception {
        DbRefResolver dbRefResolver = new DefaultDbRefResolver(mongoDbFactory());
        MappingMongoConverter converter = new MappingMongoConverter(dbRefResolver, mongoMappingContext());
        final CustomConversions conversions = customConversions();
        log.info("hasCustomWriteTarget(Period.class): " + conversions.hasCustomWriteTarget(Period.class));
        log.info("hasCustomWriteTarget(Period.class, String.class): " + conversions.hasCustomWriteTarget(Period.class, String.class));
        log.info("hasCustomReadTarget(String.class, Period.class): " + conversions.hasCustomReadTarget(String.class, Period.class));
        converter.setCustomConversions(conversions);
        converter.afterPropertiesSet(); //probably not needed, trying out of despair
        return converter;
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public CustomConversions customConversions() {
        List<Converter> converters = new ArrayList<>();
        converters.add(new Converters.PeriodToStringConverter());
        converters.add(new Converters.StringToPeriodConverter());
        return new CustomConversions(converters);
    }
```

When I start my app I see in the logs:

```
hasCustomWriteTarget(Period.class): true
hasCustomWriteTarget(Period.class, String.class): true
hasCustomReadTarget(String.class, Period.class): true
```

Now I create a new `Foo` and save it to my repository:

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
foo.setPeriod(Period.of(2, 0, 1));
fooRepository.save(foo);
```

Now the weirdness happens:

In Mongodb I see:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("xxxx"),
  "period": {
      "years" : 0,
      "months" : 2,
      "days" : 1
    }
}
```

So already that's something wrong. It should be saved as a `String`

When I try to read the object in Java I get:

```
org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingException: No property null found on entity class java.time.Period to bind constructor parameter to!
```

I debugged the code in `MappingMongoConverter`:

```
    if (conversions.hasCustomReadTarget(dbo.getClass(), rawType)) {
        return conversionService.convert(dbo, rawType);
    }
```

because my object was not store as a String the `dbo` variable is actually a `BasicDbObject` and therefore I don't have converter for this.

Any idea why my write converter is not being used to persist the `Period`?

I have `jackson-datatype-jdk8` on my classpath, could it be the issue? Would jackson be involved at all for persisting in Mongodb?

**EDIT**

It seems to be a registration issue. When I debug the code, the `CustomConversion` object used in `MappingMongoConverter` is different than the one I create. And it doesn't have the custom converters which I create

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK it was extremely stupid...

I was also creating my own `MongoTemplate`:

```
@Bean
public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws Exception {
    return new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory());
}
```

Which basically ignores my custom converter. To fix it:

```
@Bean
public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws Exception {
    return new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory(), mappingMongoConverter());
}
```

Comment: This helped me, however why create our own `MongoTemplate`? Your method is identical to the default (superclass) implementation.

Comment: It's because in my case I was using a custom `MongoDBFactory`. I guess if you don't you can use the default implementation as you suggested

Comment: To give you the whole story it's because I had to do something like `mongodbFactory.setMongoTemplate(mongoTemplate);` inside this method. Otherwise you are right it's a bit useless